# VBA delete multiple rows after AutoFilter at once using xlCellTypeVisible is throwing error

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have an AutoFilter on a table that filters down the table properly where a column doesn't equal the string value provided. I then want to delete all of the visible rows that are left unfiltered (maybe 1000 to 2000 rows at once max). However I get an error on the `EntireRow.Delete` method. Here's my code, how can I successfully delete these rows all at once?

```
Dim columnFilter As String
columnFilter = "Foo"

Set tbl = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

tbl.AutoFilter
tbl.AutoFilter Field:=columnNum, Criteria1:="<>" & columnFilter

'***Error thrown here
tbl.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Error given is: `Run-time error '1004': Delete method of Range class failed.`

Comment: Don't use `.Usedrange` like this. Stick with the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) instead and offset to retain the header.

Comment: Still gives me the same error of `Run-time error '1004': Delete method of Range class failed.` I've updated my code to show use of the `CurrentRegion` property.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use .Usedrange like this. Stick with the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) instead and offset to retain the header.

There is also a caution that comes with deleting visible rows left visible after an [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) has been implemented. You should *always* check to ensure that at least one row was left visible after the criteria has been applied before the delete operation. There are a number of ways to do that; this is one involving the native worksheet [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af)'s ability to exclude non-visible rows from its calculations.

Another issue is confusing a structured Table [ListObject object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247(v=office.11).aspx) with regular worksheet data. A structured table requires special consideration. I've added code in the routine below to test for the filtered area being a ListObject table and decide between two methods of deleting the rows based on that determination.

```
Sub fooFilter()
    Dim columnFilter As String, columnNum As Long

    columnFilter = "Foo"
    columnNum = 1

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=columnNum, Criteria1:="<>" & columnFilter

            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(columnNum))) Then
                    'very simple test to see if we are in a ListObject or not
                    If .ListObject Is Nothing Then
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                    Else
                        .EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            End With

            'leave filter there but clear the filter
            .AutoFilter Field:=columnNum
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If you are trying to delete all the way down to the bottom of the worksheet¹ you should get a

```
Run-time error: '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

The above error has nothing to do with limitations on how many rows you can delete. The problem is that you are trying to use [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) before resizing the associated range. Without resizing, you are trying to push the range off the sheet by the number of rows in the .Offset. .Resize to one row less first, then offset to save your header.

There is a certain volatility to the [.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215923%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and I use it less and less for anything at all.

There is a MS KB whitepaper on the problem with attempting to delete rows there none are showing. See [Deleting or modifying rows that are above and below a hidden row in a filtered Excel 2007 worksheet also deletes or modifies the hidden row](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928974) for details.

¹Having a worksheet legitimately populated to the very last row is very rare. It is much more likely that the worksheet is exhibiting a false [xlCellTypeLastCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlcelltype.aspx) property due to a rogue value or over zealous formatting. Correcting the worksheet to properly reflect the extents of the actual data should come before adjusting coding to compensate for a problem with the worksheet.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this is still giving me the same exact error on the same exact line: `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`. I wish a better explanation of the error was available.

Comment: Are you working on an actual ListObject table or just using the term table to describe a block of data on the worksheet? If it is an actual table, you should be using the VBA references for a ListObject table, not for free data in a worksheet. (that code was tested on a simple block of data starting in A1)

Comment: It's not an actual ListObject table, just the block of data as you said. Could it be that there are too many rows trying to be deleted at once? Is it possible to split up in batches? Deleting works when I do it row by row, but it takes entirely too long to execute for many sheets, which is my case.

Comment: What happens when you tap Ctrl+End? Where do you end up?

Comment: No, there is no limitation on deleting rows like you are unless your .UsedRange extends to the bottom of the worksheet. Even that is not a limit on what you can delete. It is an error because you cannot .Offset 1 row down before you .Resize to one row less. See above for a change in the order of .Offset and .Resize.

Comment: Still same issue after changing around the offset and resize, Unfiltered, there are only 2168 rows and it's not going anywhere near the bottom as you said. If the amount of rows is not the issue I can't see what is as it is failing on this exact line `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`